# Best data type for a dynamic DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datagridview, datasource

I'm working on a `UserControl` named **CustomizedGrid** which contains a `DataGridView` and a couple of labels for showing information about Rows.

First of all I have chosen `Linq To Sql` as the base technology for talking to SQL, so whatever I say or ask is in `Linq To Sql` framework.

**Constraint #1**: I need this **CustomizedGrid** to be able to handle Data Sources of different tables.
For example I have a **Users** table and a **Customers** table, in one form I want to pass the **Users** to the grid, and in another, the **Customers**.

**Constraint #2**: I need to store a *shadow* of the **DataSource** in order to be able to perform local searches.
For example I load all **Customers** in my grid and then I want to search for those **Customers** who have "Mahdi" in their names, and after I filtered "Mahdi", then I want to see all **Customers** again. So I want to Fetch **Customers** from DB, load them to my **Main DataSource** and also to my **Shadow DataSource**, I filter data in **Shadow DataSource** but the main data remains in the **Main DataSource** and I can load **Main DataSource** again without a redundant data fetch from DB.

---

My Question:
Which Data Type can serve me the best? I can not use a Generic List because I don't know which table will be hosted, I can not Use IQueryable because I don't know how to cast it later so that I can search for a particular field.

my information lacks in this content and your answers will actually be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You may go like this:

**Constraint 1.** You may use Join to get data from different tables.

For eg. `SELECT U.ID,U.NAME, C.NAME AS CUSTOMERNAME, C.DOB FROM USER U INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON U.ID = C.USERID`

And Fill a DataTable with this query like adp.fill(datatable,query);
Bind this datatable to your customized Datagridview like `customDataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;`

**Contraint 2.** To filter data in a datagridview, you may use following :

```
((DataTable)DataGridViews.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter =colmNameHere " like '%" + filterTextHere + "%'";
```

Join using Linq

```
var query = from c in customers
        join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
        select new { c.Name, o.Product };
```

Comment: thanks for the second part, but for the first part I meant I want the DataSource to be able to get data from different tables, let's say get Users in frmUsers and Customers in frmCust, so I don't want joining tables, I want the DataSource to do it's job with different tables. And I think using a DataTable will do it, the only disadvantage is that I have to convert IQueryable to DataTable which is not built-in available and also may take time itself. Is there a better way?

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari I have added 'join using linq', this will definitely solve your purpose.